# Recursive checkin using Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I want to check in a directory and all the sub-directories into the clear case.
Is there a specific command to achieve it?
Currently I am going into each directory and manually checking in each file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577/how-do-i-perform-a-recursive-checkout-using-clearcase):

> Now the problem is to checkin everything that has changed.
>   It is problematic since often not everything has changed, and ClearCase will trigger an error message when trying to check in an identical file. Meaning you will need 2 commands:

```
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "ci -nc \"%n\"\n" | ct
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "unco -rm %n\n" | ct
```

(with 'ct being 'cleartool' : type 'doskey ct=cleartool $*' on Windows to set that alias)

---

But if by "checkin" you mean:

- "enter into source control for the first time"
- "updating a large number of files which may have changed on an existing versionned directory"

I would recommend creating a dynamic view and clearfsimport your snapshot tree (with the new files) in the dynamic view.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172510/how-to-track-third-party-sources-with-clearcase-without-a-headache) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively).

> the clearfsimport script is better equipped to import multiple times the same set of files, and automatically:

- add new files,
- make new version of existing files previously imported (but modified in the source set of files re-imported)
- remove files already imported but no longer present in the source set of files.
- make a clear log of all operations made during the import process.

:

```
 clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\sourceDir\* m:\MyView\MyVob\MyDestinationDirectory
```

Comment: I keep googling this answer and every time I forget to change the escape characters. In Linux the commands are [ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "ci -nc "%n"\n" | ct] and [ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "unco -rm "%n"\n" | ct]

Comment: @JordanBentley are you sure you cannot escape double quotes within double quotes? I would understand if the `ci` or `unco` commands were within simple quotes (in which case the double quotes aren't immediately interpreted by the shell)

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I was using the c-shell, which handles double quotes differently.

Answer (score 1):

did you used -recurse option in the clearfsimport command.
Example: clearfsimport -recurse source_dir .

This should help.
If you're using the Windows client, right-click on the parent folder, select Search, leave the file name field empty, click Search, select all the files in the result window (ctrl-A), right-click on them and select ClearCase -> Add to Source Control

Answer (score 1):

If you are in windows you may try,

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`cleartool lsco -cview -me -r -s`) do cleartool ci -nc %i
```