# Clearcase CASE INSENSITIVITY

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to write a windows batch file to automate the checkout/check-in process for the ClearCasr tool but facing an issue with Case letters of the file name.

For example: if filename is "`Hello_Working.txt`" when I copied to my vob its becoming "`hello_working.txt`".
So when I do a checkout/check-in its prompting error as "Pathname not found".

I know MVFS "Clear Preserve" will solve the problem but if we change the setting other vobs which are running will affect, My admin suggested that your batch file script commands has to negotiate the cases of the file name. I am writing the command as below

Checkout:

```
ct co -nc H:\test1_view\test1_vob\Hello_working.txt
ct co -cfile "Comment"
```

Checkin:

```
ct ci -nc H:\test1_view\test1_vob\Hello_working.txt
ct ci -cfile "Comment"
```

Please let me know what needs to modify in the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to `co/ci -nc`, and then `co/ci -cfile "comment"`.

You can checkout with comment, and then `ci -nc`: a checkin without comment will use by default the comment given in the checkout step.

```
ct co -c "Comment" H:\test1_view\test1_vob\Hello_working.txt
ct ci -nc H:\test1_view\test1_vob\Hello_working.txt
```

Second, you can try checkin all the checked-out files, as in "[Recursive checkin using Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973956/recursive-checkin-using-clearcase/974016#974016)", which would make ClearCase find the right name (even when the filename is [converted to lowercase in Windows dynamic view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_netadm_case_mvfs.htm)).

```
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "ci -nc \"%n\"\n" | ct
```

Even for one file, try the command [`ct lsco` (`cleartool lscheckout`)](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm) in order to ask ClearCase for the right name.

Comment: @user2487946 I prefer keeping answering questions on Stack Overflow, for others to benefit from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165545/clearcase-case-issue, Please find the link and let me know