# How to check in all checked out files in a folder via ClearCase Connector in IBM RAD

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rad

How do I check in all checked out files that are in a folder (and any of its sub-folders) inside of RAD?

I have the ClearCase Connector installed and I can individually check in files, but I have worked on a bunch of files that all roll up into the same folder and would like to check them in all at once if possible. I can also select files one-by-one using CTRL + click and then check them all in at once, but this seems like more of a hassle then it should be.

I am much more familiar with subversion and git, which easily allow me to do a similar operation and I am hoping ClearCase allows this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the issue with ClearCase: it is a file-centric CVCS (Centralized VCS), as opposed to git (revision-centric DVCS or Distributed VCS).
See "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)" for more on the differences between the two.

If you have a full ClearCase installation in addition of your RAD, then you can directly checkin all checked out files, like in "[Recursive checkin using Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974016/6309)".

But if you are using CCRC, it is not so easy to chain multiple checkins, beside the "multiple selection" that you are using.

As the [OP nerdherd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222654/nerdherd) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252967/6309), CCRC GUI has a **find checkout option** (mentioned in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21211591)), which will allow to list and check those in through an (again) multiple selection.

Comment: Based on my less-than-stellar experience with ClearCase thus far I feared this might be the case. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do something close enough to what I wanted:

From the ClearCase menu in RAD you can open the Find Checkouts window and then all checked out files will be displayed with their full paths and sorting them will put all files in a hierarchical order. From there you can easily select all checked out files in a given parent folder and check them in at once.

I'm sure this something I should have figured out, but being new to ClearCase it wasn't immediately intuitive to me.

Comment: Sound great. +1. I have added the "find checkout" view in CCRC in my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The question is for RAD but I was using CCRC and having same question, and found that in CCRC there is an option called aggregated check-in, right click on then > Aggregated > check in...
this way it will open a window with all the checked out files and you can add comment for each file and check-in the changes.