# Clearcase adding new directories files does order matter?

Tags: clearcase

I have a huge chunk of code (directory -> sub directiories -> files everywhere) to be added to Clearcase in Windows.
I used the command 'clearfsimport -rec -nset sourcepath destinationpath' command to add them to clearcase.

I was able to successfully add it to source control but when I try to deliver it I get error saying element not visible in integration view. So does order of adding new files matters in ClearCase?

Below is the error message from ClearCase while delivering:

```
Operation started: 22-04-2015 16:13:14 Element "D:\Workspace\auto_int\ROOT\Automation@@\main\auto\1\LDSCluster\main\auto\1\SSI\main\auto\2\Service
References" is not visible in view "auto_int".
Skipping element
"D:\Workspace\auto_int\ROOT\Automation@@\main\auto\1\LDSCluster\main\auto\1\SSI\main\auto\2\Service
References".  *** IMPORTANT *** Before completing this deliver or
rebase operation, you should understand why this element is not visible.  
If this element should be visible, cancel this operation,
fix the problem, and re-run the operation.
```

Answer (score 1):

> So does order of adding new files matters in clearcase?

No it does not matter.

But check if the `clearfsimport` has left folders/files checked out.
Because they won't be visible by any "deliver" operation until [they have been checked in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974016/6309).

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for the issue as responded by folks. But the one I had is my integration view config spec doesn't load rules that captures the scope of newly added directory levels. After adding the required load rules I am able to deliver it. Thanks everyone.

(But in development view too that load rules wasn't there earlier but as I add new files it appended rules dynamically which didn't happened in case of integration view.)