# Automatically add new folders and files to source control

Tags: clearcase

We're using ClearCase, integrated with VS2008.

Problem is, adding new files into my own personal view will not be reflected when i push (check in) changes.

I have to manually add all new files/projects/items into source control and then check them in.

Is there any way to automatically be able to get all new items into source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [current solution has been added to ClearCase](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21129529) (provided the [runtime security level in .NET allows it](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21131958)), then simply adding files within a snapshot view part of Visual Studio project won't version those files:
they will still be considered private, until you "add them to source control".

If you have many new files, you can find them with this answer "[How do I determine what files in my ClearCase local view have not yet been added to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191855/how-do-i-determine-what-files-in-my-clearcase-local-view-have-not-yet-been-added)": depending on your ClearCase version, this will be more reliable than the integrated solution (as [described in this IBM technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358571) for CC 7.0.1.1, 7.0.1.2).