# Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively

Tags: command, clearcase

What is the clearcase Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The usual commands are based on [`cleartool ls`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm):

- `ct lsprivate`: but it is only for dynamic views, not snapshot views
- `ct ls -rec -view_only`: at least, it works in both snapshot and dynamic views

However both list *also* your checked-out files.

If you want only the *private* files, ie **skipping the hijacked/eclipsed/checked-out and  symlinks**, you need to filter those out.

In Windows, that would be:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do @echo "%i"
```

In Unix:

```
cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "hijacked" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v "-->" | xargs echo
```

Comment: For ct lsprivate, specifying the -other option will leave out checked-out files.

EDIT: Never mind, Otzen already said that in his answer 2 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone else reading this question here is VonC's windows solution with a couple of minor changes to run as a windows script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do @echo "%%A"
```

Replace `@echo` with `rmdir /S /Q` and `del /F` to do the actual deletions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369952/1376208). So the final script is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do rmdir /S /Q "%%A"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do del /F "%%A"
```

If you save as a .bat file under the element of the view you are cleaning from, the script will clean up by deleting itself as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

I amended the version by @MilesHampson since this returned too many results for me and, I want to run this as a batch file.

My new files won't be in the `debug` or `obj` folder and as such, I don't need to see any results for those folders... I'm also only working on C#. So that's all I need to see.

```
@echo off
setlocal

@echo Searching, please wait as this can take a while...

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->" ^| find /V "obj" ^| find /V "debug"`) do  ( 
  if "%%~xA"==".cs" echo %%A
  )
)

@echo === === === === === Search Complete === === === === === === 

pause
```

Create a bat file with the above, drop it into your root project folder and run it. It will display those not in source control.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone else reading this question, here is VonC's Unix solution with a couple of minor changes to run under Cygwin on Windows.

In Cygwin:

```
cleartool ls -rec | grep -v "Rule:" | grep -v "hijacked" | grep -v "eclipsed" | grep -v -- "-->"
```

The Cygwin line is similar to the Unix given by VonC, but note the double-dash on the last grep is needed (and the xargs is not needed).

Answer (score 2):

```
ct lsprivate -other
```

Would also filter out checked-out files

`ct lsprivate -co` : list all checked-out files

`ct lsprivate -do` : list all derived object files

`ct lsprivate -other` : list all other private files

Answer (score 0):

I followed all above solutions and it is great command. I had some more requirements that were not covered above so I modified script little more with below additional points

1. Excluded batch file from list (otherwise current batch file also coming in list)
2. Removed Directory from list as generally I am interested in file
3. Specially for java developer, excluded target folder and jar files
   as they are not generally checked in
4. Removed .classpath, .project
   and .settings folder which is specific to Eclipse (if they are same
   level as project/modules)

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal

   @echo.
   @echo Searching, please wait as this can take a while...
   @echo.
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->" ^| find /V ".settings" ^| find /V "jar" ^| find /V "keep" ^| find /V "target" ^| find /V ".classpath"  ^| find /V ".project" ^| find /V "%~n0" `) do ( if not exist %%i\* @echo "%%i")

   @echo.
   @echo === === === === === Search Complete === === === === === === 
   @echo.
   @echo.

   pause
   ```