# Find all files that are not added to ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I have created some file, in different directories. I couldn't add them when I created, so I need to do it later.

Is there a way to get the list of all the files that are in ClearCase view, that are not actually under source control?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes: you can list all your **private** files with ClearCase, with

- `cleartool lsprivate` (only for dynamic views, not snapshot views)
- `cleartool ls -rec -view_only`

You will need to grep the output for your specific file though.
See "[Command to find all view private files in the current directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657084/command-to-find-all-view-private-files-in-the-current-directory-recursively/7657120#7657120)" for more.