# Find my "hanging" checkouts from my view

Tags: version-control, clearcase, snapshot-view

I had checked-out files in a snapshot view in ClearCase.
There has been a change in the vob servers and now I have ended up in the following situation:
The files are checked-out but when I try to find them: Doing `Find Checkouts` in the view folder does not list them as check outs.
Is there a work-arround/way to be able to retrieve all these "lost" checkouts?
There are present in my view as private files but there are too many to find them manually one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to [list all your hijacked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657084/command-to-find-all-view-private-files-in-the-current-directory-recursively/7657120#7657120) and see if your checked out files are in those.

You also can do a `cleartool update`, and look at the `*.updt` file it will generate: it will list all the files which aren't updated (because they are either hijacked or checked out).

Comment: There isn't a chance that an update could delete my files and lose them for ever right?

Comment: @Jim no currently modified file would be deleted by a `cleartool update` (only a `cleartool update -overwrite` would do that). That being said, a quick save just to be sure is always a good idea ;)

Comment: `quick save`?How do I do that?

Comment: @Jim I mean, simply copy the content of your snashot view elsewhere on your hard drive (simple Windows or Unix operation, nothing to do with ClearCase).

Comment: For example I can not find option `-rec` here:http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ctintro.htm

Comment: @Jim : it lists all your files, and you can filter to detect hijacked, checked out or private files. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm does list the `-rec` option.

Comment: With `rec` you meant `–r/ecurse?

Comment: @Jim yes, `-r`, `-rec` or `-recurse`, it all the same option. But don't copy it from their documentation, though: they use '`–`' instead of '-'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed/170148#170148

Comment: I run the command `ls -rec -view_only` and it lists **all** files in the view and in some I see `Rule: CHECKEDOUT`.Is this what it does?I mean it will list **everything** and I should look for files having `Rule: CHECKEDOUT` displayed next to them?

Comment: @Jim to filter only the checked out files, yes, but it list also hijacked files. The question is: do you see your files listed as checked out or hijacked?

Comment: Yes!I see my files!I am not sure if they are all but I see many not listed in the `Find Checkouts`!

Comment: @Jim is it because they might be checked out in another view, and the find checkout only list checkouts for the current user and current view? Could you do a Find Checkout "all users / all views"?

Comment: No, this is not the case.I mean my files were all checked-out by me in this view (if this is what you mean).Because they are too many,I am not yet sure I see them all (since I might be forgetting something)

Comment: **Thanks a lot**!!!BTW what would be the command to Find Checkout "all users / all views" that you recommended?

Comment: @Jim `cleartool lscheckout` (or `cleartool lsco`). It is only when you add the options `-me` and `-cview` that you restrict the checkouts to current view and current user.