# Cannot filter by file extension in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to return a set of values which match my criteria, based upon the results of another tool!

My bat file reads a list of files using the ClearCase tool [(as per this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657084/command-to-find-all-view-private-files-in-the-current-directory-recursively), and writes them to screen. I now want to filter the results, where it only shows me the files which end with .cs (note, there may be other periods in the name)

My code

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do if %%A==*.cs @echo %%A
```

I'm lost as to why when I run the following (note the very end of the script is different)...

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"`) do @echo %%A
```

...I see lots of results (including files with the .cs extension). But, when I run the first code script, it runs but writes nothing to screen.  When I run the second code example, one of the lines I see is

I did try adding quote marks but it made no difference.

```
if "%%A"=="*.cs"
```

When I run the second piece of code, the results look like

```
.\bin\x86 
.\bin\x86\Debug
.\Debug\mywork.exe.embed.manifest  
.\obj\x86\Debug\myThings.dll  
.\Html\MyFile.cs  
.\obj\x86\Debug\MyProject\Views\File.baml  
.\obj\x86\Debug\MyProject\Views\File.g.cs  
.\obj\x86\Debug\MyProject\Views\File.g.i.cs
```

From the above, ideally I want to only see MyFile.cs (although I can easily live with all the .cs files)

Comment: Personally, I'd use `findstr /V "Rule: hijacked eclipsed -->"` in place of four cascaded `find/v`s. How is batch supposed to determine that you only want `myfile.cs`? What is the criterion for that choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check extension in a for loop, use %%~xA. It will return just the extension of file with dots.

```
if "%%~xA"==".cs"
```

Comment: ` does not suround a command in batch. Use simple quotes 'cleartool ls  -rec ^| find /V "Rule:" ^| find /V "hijacked" ^| find /V "eclipsed" ^| find /V "-->"'. In rest - you'll need to put more details, like output of cleartool.