# unable to perform delivery on clearcase because of checked out file in snapshot view?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have having an issue in clearcase delivery. There are some files that are checked out from a snapshot view and the view has been removed. I am trying to deliver from a dynamic view in unix. Since I can see those files checked out in the activity, is there a way to check in those files and proceed the delivery operation?

Comment: I used to create a new activity, move the checkout files from the old activity to the new activity, do a delivery without the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove completely the view: that will cancel the checkout state of those files, and will allow you to resume the deliver.

See "[ClearCase: Is it possible to cancel checkouts not made from your own view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520876/6309)".

```
cleartool rmview -force -uuid (uuid_of_the_view) -vob \aVob
```

You can find the uuid of the view by doing a `cleartool descr -l vob:\aVob`.

---

For snapshot views, you can regenerate the .view.dat and unco the file that way, with "[Uncheckout an element from a snapshot view when the view root directory is not accessible](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21313652)"

- List the checkouts to identify the view and checkout information
- Create a new temporary view root directory
- Regenerate the view root to the new temporary directory

  ```
  ccperl "C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\regen_view_dot_dat.pl\" -tag <view-tag> <tmp-dir>
  ```
- Cancel the checkout

  ```
  cleartool unco -rm <tmp-dir>\<vob>\<path>\<checkedout-file>
  ```
- Remove the temporary directory

  ```
  rmdir /S/Q <tmp-dir>
  ```

Comment: I am thinking to regenerate the view since I know the uuid of the view and check in the files and perform the delivery. Do you think it is worth trying this?

Comment: @user2370590 if it is a dynamic view, then yes. Not for a snapshot view: the changes would have been lost.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Checked out is cancelled by the following information.http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21313652

Comment: @user2370590 Excellent. I have included the process in the answer for more visibility.