# How to undo a checkout that has no activity attached to it

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I have a quite weird problem here with UCM-ClearCase.
A user tried to deliver from his dev-stream to the int-stream of the project. For some reason he decided that he needed to cancel the delivery and executed "deliver -cancel". According to him this did not work the first time (although he does not remember the error message) but the second time he issued the command the delivery was actually canceled.
The problem now is that he has a checkout in his int-view (!) that does not have an activity attached to it. The activity of the delivery was deleted (obviously during the cancellation of the delivery). If he tries to undo the checkout in the int-stream (by using "unco") ClearCase outputs a warning that he needs to set an activity and a view context in order to undo the checkout. Setting some activity (and a view context) is no good, the same error message appears.
EDIT:
The exact error message given by ClearCase is: 
cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view.
cleartool: Error: Unable to cancel checkout for "PathToFolder".
The checked out element is only a folder and no other elements (neither files nor folders) are checked out
END_OF_EDIT
Creating a new activity in order to attach it to the checkout did not help either as I did not find a command to attach an activity to a already checked out folder.
According to [IBM](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122515) we could remove the view and all its references and then re-create it which should solve the issue of the checkout.
I am kind of hesitant to do so without being sure that there is no other way to handle the situation (especially as the above-mentioned link states that there might be cases when removing the view does not really help). Is anyone aware of a different solution for this kind of situation?
Best Regards

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is the checked out element just a folder? Is there a file also checked out? What version of ClearCase is used here?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly, thanks for the hint

Comment: does the rmview I mention below help?

Comment: I am not sure yet as the user is situated in Singapore and has already left for today. But we will try it out tomorrow - and hope that everything works fine

Comment: Ok, again, you just have to make sure that user has no other element in checkout for that view.

Comment: Jup, already did, there's only the one folder being checked-out.

Comment: Then it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that to remove all checkouts associated with a specific vob and view is

```
cleartool rmview -force -uuid (uuid_of_the_view) -vob \aVob
```

See "[unable to perform delivery on clearcase because of checked out file in snapshot view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388200/6309)"

Simply make sure the user has no other checked out files.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help yet again

Comment: Why do I have to make sure the user has no other checked out files ?
What would happen else ?

Comment: @andymeissner Let me remember (7 years later): those checkout files would loose their "checkout" status, which means someone else could checkout/checkin them before that user, who first did the checkout, becomes aware of the new situation.