# How to undo checkout a file checked out from another user?

Tags: clearcase

In this example, the user5628 (which is actually sick) has a checked out file in its dynamic view. How can I cancel this checkout?

```
$ ct lsco -all | ag foo
2013-08-29     user52001    checkout version "L:\a\path\foo.c" from \main\branch_a\0 (reserved)
2014-04-10     user5030     checkout version "L:\a\path\foo.c" from \main\branch_b\0 (reserved)
--11-18T08:29  user52212    checkout version "L:\a\path\foo.c" from \main\branch_c\1 (reserved)
--04-15T14:24  user5628     checkout version "L:\a\path\foo.c" from \main\branch_d\11 (reserved)
--04-30T08:05  user5072     checkout version "L:\a\path\foo.c" from \main\branch_d\11 (unreserved)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[ClearCase: Is it possible to cancel checkouts not made from your own view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520876/6309)", the easiest way is to remove the "checkout" status for user5628 view.

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\avob
# get user5628 view uuid in the output
cleartool rmview -force -uuid (uuid_of_the_view) -vob \aVob
```

That will not modify any of user5628's checked out files (the modification are not lost), but user5628 will have to check them out again.

That same technique is useful when you have [old checked out files in a view which has since then been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101992/6309).

Comment: I saw this post but I did not understand how to get the `-uuid (uuid_of_the_view)` from by `ct lsco -all`

Comment: @nowox I understand. I have edited http://stackoverflow.com/a/7520876/6309 to make that step clearer.

Comment: @nowox : be aware that ALL checkout by the user in that VOB will be uncheckedout. I have commented on [link](stackoverflow.com/a/7520876/6309). It can be a problem if the user have several file checkedout in the VOB and you want to uncheckout only a subset of them.

Comment: @nowox He (iclman) meant to say he [commented here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29983495/6309)