# Undo a checkout that has no activity attached to it

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

Somehow one of my checkouts in UCM has no  activity attached to it and when i try to to undo checkout, it says that cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view. Has anyone come across this kind of scenario? Please advise. 
According to IBM we could remove the view and all its references and then re-create it which should solve the issue of the checkout.

Is there a way to find what has gone wrong and any suggestions to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> According to IBM we could remove the view and all its references and then re-create it which should solve the issue of the checkout.

Yes, it is [the nuke-view approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520876/6309):

```
cleartool rmview -force -uuid (uuid_of_the_view) -vob \aVob
```

Keep it mind it will cancel *any* checkout produced by that view.

> Is there a way to find what has gone wrong and any suggestions to fix the issue?

Maybe the activity was somehow deleted, leaving the checked out version "orphaned" (in term of activity, that is).

An [`cleartool lshistory -minor`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm) on the vob (`vob:\avob`) for instance, or the element of the file (`path/to/file@@`) might reveal some event which could shed light on this circumstance.