# Clearprompt command: Element-list generation

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

In view of my previous question [Script for recursive add-to-source control: How to ignore specific files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888121/script-for-recursive-add-to-source-control-how-to-ignore-specific-files-and-fol), an issue that arose in regard to the command `clearprompt` (whereby to generate a list of elements for source control) is that it has restrictions on the number of elements it can process. So my question is: **Is there a way to allow for a larger number of elements?**

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 1):

[`clearprompt`](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/cc_family/ccase/doc/all/cc_ref/clearprompt.htm) has some limitation, in term of size, number of character per lines, and as you see, number of elements.
Those aren't fixed, on Windows or Unix, as far as I know.

So it is best to split your list, and to display several clearprompt dialogs, with a header specifying the number of said dialog over the total of number of windows expected (1/6, 2/6, 3/6, ...)

The only other solution would be to rely on another library to dispolay that dialog, but the advantage of using `ccperl` is that it is installed with the ClearCase client, which means it is available on all client workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I encounter a similar issue where because of this limit, the clearprompt dialog was empty. I debugged the script and the error seems to be because of the system limit of the max command line which was passed to `echo` in the following statement

```
`echo $listelement > $list_add`
```

I just changed this line to the following

```
open(LIST_ADD,">".$list_add);
print LIST_ADD $listelement; 
close(LIST_ADD);
```

or basically, instead of relying on the shell to copy the content, I am doing the same through perl and that resolved the issue.