# clearcase - how can i tell if a file i have checked out unreserved has been updated?

Tags: clearcase

I come from SVN. I'm new to clearcase:  I have a number of unreserved checkouts (for local config purposes) that are occasionally updated by others on the project.  What clearcase command can I run to determine which of my unreserved checkouts have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way (ClearCase only mention the existence of a new version [during the reconciliation of an hijacked version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741062/6309))

[Hijacked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309) are [still listed (`cleartool ls`) with their version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123318)

```
%> cleartool ls

archive.ppt@@\main\1 [hijacked]         Rule: \main\LATEST
project.doc@@\main\1                    Rule: \main\LATEST
doc_resources.ppt@@\main\2 [hijacked]   Rule: \main\LATEST
```

One solution would be, [for each hijacked files found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191964/6309), to compare that verison (in the not-yet-updated snapshot view) with the same `cleartool ls file` done in a [*dynamic* view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) with the same config spec as the snapshot view: if the version in the dynamic view differs, there should be a new version created.