# How to add a directory tree to a ClearCase repository?

Tags: unix, clearcase

I have a directory tree with sub-directories, and I want to add it to a ClearCase repository. Currently I need to rename the directory, use CC's mkdir, and so forth for every dir. Is there a way to do this automatically (maybe a ClearCase command I don't know about, or a script)?

Comment: I was answering your question! Rename your private dir, and use it as source for your clearfsimport. And please restore your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247154/how-to-add-a-directory-tree-to-a-clearcase-repository-in-place

Comment: @VonC Sorry, I figured out the answer, like you said. When I go to the link, I get "Page Not Found". Is it lost forever? Do you want me to repost it so you can answer it? Sorry for the mess.

Comment: I thought you were able to undelete your own question, but then maybe not ;) I can only vote for its un-deletion, so the simplest way would be to repost, if you think it can have added value for others.

Comment: @VonC asked on meta, a moderator restored it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using **`clearfsimport`**.
See:

- "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively/144310#144310)".
- "[Creating a new subdirectory structure in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196)"

What is nice with this script is that is will:

- checkout the parent directories,
- make the necessary `mkdir` for adding new directories
- do the `mkelem` for adding new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Clearteam Explorer has a recursive add to source control, at least for web views - AFAIK