# How to add a directory tree to a ClearCase repository in-place?

Tags: unix, clearcase

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352366/how-to-add-a-directory-tree-to-a-clearcase-repository) regarding ClearCase, but it doesn't work when I have a private directory in a vob, and I want to add it recursively to the repository in-place. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a private directory, the nominal way would be to:

- **rename** it first (still keeping it in its same parent directory)
- use the new name of that directory as sources for your `clearfsimport` (that I describe in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352366/how-to-add-a-directory-tree-to-a-clearcase-repository) you mention in your question)

That is not always ideal, because of processes that could have handle on sole of the files of your private directory, but if this isn't the case, then you can use this process to quickly add your directory and all its sub-elements to ClearCase.