# How to add all the files in a folder to source control via cleartool command?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am having a folder where lot of files and subfolders , adding it to source control via UI is consuming much time.

How to add all the files (including files inside subfolder) to source control using cleartool?

(I am using clearcase UCM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively)", `clearfsimport` is the way to go.

However, `clearfsimport` will take a source an import it in your view, so:

- it is best to keep the source *outside* your view (to avoid confusion when ClearCase tries to add the source file in the destination which is the same directory)
- you must "clean out" the source directories first (because the `clearfsimport` command will import... *all* the files under the root directory you mention)

See "[Creating a new subdirectory structure in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196)" as an example: you can *preview* the result of an import first.

Answer (score 0):

Please user clearfsimport or if you are working with eclipse or Intellij then there are plugins from sourceforge (eclipse) which has a options to share entire project at once to CLearcase , Below are the plugin details.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/
Note : Clearcase has a limitation that if there is a text file with more than 8000 characters in single line , There is error at run time using clearfimport utility, This can be solved by writing your own bash script to do recursive checkin by handling the exception case . Hope it helps .

Answer (score -1):

I saw another comment from a similar clearcase question that suggested typing in '*' in the topmost directory required, select all, rc->cc->add to source control.