# ClearCase : how to revert / get a snapshot view of a specific date/baseline?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

My problem is with UCM ClearCase. I made a mistake a few days back in which, apparently, I have overwritten the result of a merge (from a stream rebase) of quite a few files with an old version.

I would like to get a snapshot of my stream before I made this mistake so that I can manually merge my changes back in (I have a snapshot of it as well). Then, I'll put the result in ClearCase as a new version, and everything would be back to normal.

So, how can I get a snapshot of a specific date ?

If that can help, at that date, I made a baseline.

I absolutely need something automatic because there are several hundreds of files that were changed, and I can't manually check them all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dynamic view, non-UCM, with a time - based selection rule in order to see your files at this date.

See [Get all versions from a specific time - ClearCase UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703227/get-all-versions-from-a-specific-time-clearcase-ucm/10703661)

Then you can `clearfsimport` those files back into your snapshot view, in order to effectively revert your changes.

See [How to add all the files in a folder to source control via cleartool command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891096/how-to-add-all-the-files-in-a-folder-to-source-control-via-cleartool-command)

---

Note: if you did a baseline (incremental or full, it doesn't matter) which represents the files you want to see, you could simply:

- make a sub-stream under the stream where you made said baseline
- rebase it on that new sub-stream
- `clearfsimport` from the view on the substream to your snapshot view.