# Is it possible to check the history of the files in a clearcase view?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, config-spec

I had some files in my view few days back and I need to recreate those files. Now I want to see which file changed from that period of time. Is it possible in clearcase to see the history of the view and to check what are the files that were changed from that period of time?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a snapshot view with time-based selection rules, with a config spec similar to:

```
element /myPath/... .../StreamName/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

To quickly list all modified files since a certain daye, use a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) command:

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

Not only can you compare it with your current view, and find what has changed, but you also can copy over the older files in your current view.

See also:

- [ClearCase : how to revert / get a snapshot view of a specific date/baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532942/clearcase-how-to-revert-get-a-snapshot-view-of-a-specific-date-baseline/13533056#13533056)
- [Get all versions from a specific time - ClearCase UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703227/get-all-versions-from-a-specific-time-clearcase-ucm/10703661)
- [Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676263/find-files-in-clearcase-view-newer-than-a-specific-date/7676484#7676484)