# How to delete file elements by file extension in ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have tons of `xxx.cmd` files that sit in multiple folders (e.g. `child1`, `child2`, `child3`, etc), they have a parent folder `parent`

Is there a cleartool command that I can executes on the `parent`folder that deletes all the `.cmd` files in all children folders?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily, because you need to checkout any parent directory including those files, before doing the `cleartool rmname`.

The easiest would be to:

- Copy all your elements *outside* the view.
- remove all the *.cmd file (using any find utility you want, nothing to do with clearcase)
- [`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196) back those files into your view (minus the *.cmd files removed), with the option **-rmname** ("mirror clearfsimport"):

  - none of the *existing* files will be affected
  - the *.cmd files present in the *destination* (your ClearCase view), but no longer present in the source (your backup where you cleaned and removed those files), will be removed (rmnamed), with the fastidious checkout-checkin of the parent directories done for you.

  –rmname

> For all source-name arguments that are directories, performs an `rmname` operation on elements that are **already in the VOB but are not present in the source directory**.
>   If used in combination with `-recurse`, performs this `rmname` operation in all directories traversed.
>   If used in combination with `-downcase`, performs the `downcase` operation before looking for matching names in the VOB.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but it does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need today and was not very happy with the proposition of using `clearfsimport` because of the need to make a local copy. This what I have done in a bash environment (msys under windows for me):

1. List all files to delete using `find`:
   `find parent -name "*.cmd" | tee to_remove_list.txt`
2. Extract a list of folders:
   `sort to_remove_list.txt | xargs -i dirname {} | uniq | tee to_checkout.txt`
3. Check-out all those folders:
   `cat to_checkout.txt | xargs -i cleartool co -nc {}`
4. Remove the files:
   `cat to_remove_list.txt | xargs -i cleartool rm {}`
5. Check-in all folders:
   `cat to_checkout.txt | xargs -i cleartool ci -nc {}`
6. (Optional) clean-up the folders and file lists:
   `rm to_remove_list.txt to_checkout.txt`