# clearfsimport does not remove files at the component root dir

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am using this command line to import files into a VOB:

```
clearfsimport -recurse -rmname -nsetevent -filter <sourceDir>/* <vobComponentRootDir>
```

Content of sourceDir:

```
fileA
fileB
```

Content of `vobComponentRootDir` before import:

```
fileC
```

Content of `vobComponentRootDir` after import:

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

`fileC` is not removed, despite I used '-rmname' option.
I suspect it is because it is at the root of the component

I want to automate this import and have the same content in `sourceDir` and `vobComponentRootDir`.

How can I complete this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-rmname` option that I mentioned in "[How to delete file elements by file extension in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346251/6309)" for [`clearfsimport`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-2-0-6) might now always work:

- "[`clearfsimport -rmname` may not detect removed directories if wildcards are used to specify source directories](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21367122)"
- "[**`clearfsimport -rmname` does not work for files at the root directory**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC48362)"

The second link is relevant here and would explain why fileC remains.

> This is working as designed.
> The `-rmname` option only applies to directories and you must be in a vob directory when you run the command.

It is best to not use a full vob as a component, but to use a multi-component vob.

If not possible, then you can try and move the content of `vobComponentRootDir` in a `subfolder` (just for the `clearfsimport` to work): `vobComponentRootDir\subfolder`.
And move that same content back in `vobComponentRootDir` once the cleafsimport is completed.