# Cleartool findmerge select changes from file 2 by default in all cases?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

So I have a branch is that is dreadfully out of date with the rest of the world. I'd love to simply create a new branch and merge over... but that task would be even larger... anyways what I'm trying to figure out is if I can set `findmerge` to always accept file 2. To speed my merge up, I initially did:

```
cleartool findmerge <path to out of date code> -ftag <my merge from view> -merge -abort
```

to cover all the simple merges, but not I want to grab the 'conflicting' changes, but I really just want all changes from from 'file 2'.

Is there an easy way or flag to provide to `findmerge` to do that?
Or do I have to go file by file and choose each change individually?

At the end of the day, I want what is an branch that has for a specified folder what is exactly in the merge from area.

I'm guessing the answer is 'no' but I have hope, and my figures are getting tired of pressing the return key :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of "reset" merge, where you want one branch content to (after merge) mirror the content of the source of that merge (`2`), I don't use findmerge at all.

I set an activity (if I am on UCM), and I initiate a [`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236945/6309) in order to import data from the source view to the destination view.

I then create merge arrows between any visible version of the source view and their matching element in the destination view (as in "[how to ignore files when finishing private ClearCase branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166384/6309)", or "[Merge arrow in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397867/6309)" -- that is the [red merge arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464236/6309) --, also used in "[How to perform a trivial merge of a binary file in a ClearCase VOB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122828)")

```
cleartool merge -ndata -to aFile -version /main/a/SourceVersion /main/a/DestVersion
```

That way, one source branch has been merged to the destination, and the source content has been copied over the destination view content.

Comment: thanks.... I'm not using UCM. I'll keep this in mind for the next time I get out of sync. I'm almost done hitting return :-)

Comment: The answer is valid for non UCM as well

Comment: can I do that ndata line with a directory? aka: 'cleartool merge -ndata -to aFolder -ver .../SourceVer .../DestVer'

Comment: @ckcin sure, you have to actually: all files and folders must have their red arrow (after completion of the clearfsimport) for the merge to be complete.