# ClearCase: When using clearfsimport to perform a reset merge, how can I keep it from creating evil twins?

Tags: clearcase

I had the same question as posted here:

[Cleartool findmerge select changes from file 2 by default in all cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865037/cleartool-findmerge-select-changes-from-file-2-by-default-in-all-cases/28865347#28865347)

I tried the recommended fix (performing a clearfsimport from the source view to the destination view).  I did this by (on Linux) setting a dynamic view for the destination, cd-ing into the VOB tag, then using `/view/[source_viewname]/[vobname]/*` as the source for the `clearfsimport`.  The problem with this is that it attempts to create evil twins, which doesn't help the situation.

Are there any other ways of doing what's being asked in the original question posted above?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a mixed approach:

- use `findmerge -ftag -merge -abort`, as suggested: that should at least merge the folders.
- for each folder where there is a conflict, use clearfsimport.

The key, to avoid any evil twin, is to make sure the folder is merged first (that will create entries for the files of that folder).
Then the `clearfsimport` won't try to create new files, but will update those entries, avoiding the evil twins.

The [OP karl_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5220834/karl) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974554/clearcase-when-using-clearfsimport-to-perform-a-reset-merge-how-can-i-keep-it/31974737#comment51927604_31974737):

> I think I'll do the following:
>
> `findmerge -type d -abort` on the first pass, let manual merges fail
>   `findmerge -type d -exec "ct merge (manually merge the element from source)"`
>
> `findmerge -type f -abort` on this pass, let manual merges fail
>   `findmegre -type f -exec "ct merge (manually merge the element from source)"`

That is the right plan: first merge folders, then files. That way, no evil twins.

Comment: You know what?  Thinking about the whole thing a little more, I think I'll do the following:

*findmerge -type d -abort        on the first pass, let manual merges fail
*findmerge -type d -exec "ct merge (manually merge the element from source)"
*findmerge -type f -abort         on this pass, let manual merges fail
*findmegre -type f -exec "ct merge (manually merge the element from source)"

That should do it all, right?

Comment: @karl_ I like the idea: first merge folders, then files. I have included your proposition in the answer for more visibility.