# cleartool findmerge and label

Tags: merge, clearcase, cleartool

I am attempting to write a script for Base ClearCase that will find all the files on a given branch and label, and perform a trivial merge of those files to another branch, and then label the newly merged files with a different label.

For example, given files on branch `\main\Proj\Proj_INT1` and labeled `Ver4`, I want to merge the files to the `\main\Proj` branch and label them with `Ver4X` (iff they are in need of merging).

I know that I can use `-fver "\main\Proj\Proj_INT1\Ver4"` to find the versions of files I want to merge, but I am not sure how to combine the merge with applying the label.

From the documentation, it does not look possible to do a `cleartool findmerge ... -merge -exec "cleartool mklabel ..."`, so I am currently attempting to a `cleartool findmerge ... -log <out_file.log> -print`, and then parse the resulting log to get all the file versions.  However, given that the `findmerge` command stops at directories, I would need to repeat this operation multiple times until all directories and files are merged (a bit of a headache to try to script and parse cleartool output).

**Is there an idiomatic or simple way to perform a merge and then label the files?**  Perhaps I can perform the merge and have cleartool generate a log which shows what the versions for merged files (so I can then label)?

Additionally, if I perform a `cleartool findmerge ... -merge` operation, **how does it handle non-trivial merges?**  I am not expecting any non-trivial merges, but I would like to skip with an error or stop the merge entirely if a non-trivial merge is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[ClearCase: When using clearfsimport to perform a reset merge, how can I keep it from creating evil twins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31974737/6309)", you need to:

- [`findmerge`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm) folders first (`-type d`), then files (`-type f`)
- use `findmerge -abort` in order to resolve any manual merge which would cause the findmerge to fail.

Instead of using `findmerge ... -merge`, I was using `-exec "cleartool merge $CLEARCASE_PN..."` using [`cleartool merge`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm) syntax.

Comment: The real question is about also labeling the files.  Are you suggesting that I do a `-exec "cleartool merge ... && cleartool mklabel ..."`, or can I somehow get the new version from the findmerge command to then parse and use to `cleartool mklabel` in a loop?

Comment: @Darthfett the first approach should work, as the merged version would be the LATEST and current one in the destination view.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation now, and it looks like I need to have the file checked out before merging?  Would you agree that it now looks more like `-exec "cleartool checkout ... && cleartool merge ... && cleartool checkin ... && cleartool mklabel"`?

Comment: Yes, I agree, checkout then merge, first the folders, then the files

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's not going to be possible since I can't specify the file path without the version information in order to perform the merge.  I guess I'll go with my backup solution of performing the merge and hoping the version information is printed out during the `findmerge`.

Comment: @Darthfett Instead of chaincing cleartool command, call a script of your own (perl, bash, any scripting language). In it, you can extract the file path you need in order to checkout.