# Cleartool command to copy the directory and its contents from local file system to VOB

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

How to Copy the directory and its contents from local file system to VOB (Source control)

I know there are commands (`mkdir`, `mkelem`) to create directory , elements and copy the files one by one.
But I would like to know is there any easy way to do this as there are thousands of sub directories and files inside parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you can use **[`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm)**, which is made precisely for that.

It will do the `mkdir`, and `cleartool mkelem` (or `cleartool checkout` if you import new versions on top of existing versioned elements)

See also "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)":

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\sourceDir\* m:\MyView\MyVob\MyDestinationDirectory
```

About the `clearfsimport` options used here, see "[Creating a new subdirectory structure in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418196/6309)".

Comment: Yes i tried that .But , it is not copying directories or contents..printing some statements like below  :      /vobs/adp01cv/adp_web/src/deployment/ADP/win32_service/ADPConsoleAll/ADPConsole09022016/Uploader/sample/controls  new directory
/vobs/adp01cv/adp_web/src/deployment/ADP/win32_service/ADPConsoleAll/ADPConsole09022016/Uploader/sample  new directory                                     
/vobs/adp01cv/adp_web/src/deployment/ADP/win32_service/ADPConsoleAll/ADPConsole09022016/Uploader/extras  new directory

Comment: @Gopi That is the `-preview` option explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/418196/6309 as I mention in the answer. Once you are satisfied with the -preview option, remove it to do the actual import.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I haven't actually understood the purpose of -preview. It worked .

Comment: @Gopi Well done! Considering http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, you could consider revisiting your older questions: some of them might deserve an "accepted answer" as well.