# clearfsimport Permission denied even with "–nsetevent" option for regular users

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Here is the command I ran as a regular user, an the error I am getting:

```
M:\my_Dyn_Admin_View>clearfsimport -preview –nsetevent C:\temp\test.txt \
                                   M:\my_Dyn_Admin_View\Admin\test

clearfsimport: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or privileged user.

clearfsimport: Error: Unable to import into "M:\my_Dyn_Admin_View\Admin\test".
```

Then I have used "`cleartool describe`" to get the "remote" setting, and printout has below line:

```
modification by remote privileged user: allowed*
```

Any ideas what might have caused this error?

clearfsimport works for admin users in my tests, but we would like it to work for regular users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned [clearfsimport in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418196/6309) and pointed to "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)" regarding the `-nset` (`nsetevent`)

As mentioned in [`clearfsimport` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearimport.htm):

> You must be root (UNIX and Linux) or the VOB owner to run clearimport unless you invoke it with the -nsetevent option

So it should work.

Here it does not work, because your option -nsetevent is not recognized.

It is not recognized because you are using `–` instead of `-`.

See "[What's the toughest bug you ever found and fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309)"

Retype the command, but manually type each '`-`'.

Comment: I have tried without "-nsnerevent" option. Still getting the same error. Also according to the manual (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm), I think you probably got it vice versa?  The manual says "You must be root (UNIX and Linux) or the VOB owner to run clearfsimport unless you invoke it with the -nsetevent option."

Comment: @riceball I have rewritten the answer. Reload the page.

Comment: @riceball My original answer was flawed.

Comment: Wow, that is it!!!! Thanks a million!!! I have no way to figure it out!

Comment: @riceball A classic case of em dash vs. en dash (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)

Comment: Just looked through the link. You are such a learned person. I learned something new today