# what is the difference between branch and branch type in rational clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am new to clearcase and it looks so confusing about branch and branch type and label and label type etc...

If i use this command:

```
cleartool mklbtype
```

What it will create, a label or a label type?

IBM Rational clearcase http://www.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/

We recently moved from subversion to clearcase for version control and when I relate the both terms it is quite confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A branch belongs to an element (a file or directory).  A brtype or branch type is a name for some branches, which can be applied to any number of elements.

For example, file.c@@/main/int is a branch of the element file.c.  Its brtype is int.  And file.c@@/main/int/2 is a version which belongs to that branch.

Similarly, a label belongs to a version of an element.  An lbtype or label type is the name for some labels, and can be applied to any number of versions of different elements.  A common use is to create labels with the same type for each element in your repository, to stamp a certain release.

```
cleartool mklbtype -global TEST
```

makes a label type.

```
cleartool mklabel TEST file.c
```

creates a label on the version of element file.c which is currently selected in your view.  Now file.c@@TEST is a permanent synonym for that version.

```
cleartool mklabel -rec TEST .
```

does the same for the current directory and all its contents, recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Addition for those using ClearCase UCM:

One other difference between branch and branch type is the kind of metadata you can find associated with a branch type.

An UCM stream will be "guarded" a branch type, meaning it will be associated with a branch pattern, and if you change the name of the UCM Stream, you will also change the name of the underlying `brtype`.

Similarly, an UCM baseline will guard the `lbtype` corresponding to the physical label of the baseline applied to each versions included in said baseline.
You cannot use `mklabel` with an `lbtype` guarded by a baseline, because baselines are supposed to be immutable.

---

You can see an application of creating `lbtype` when adding said labels after an svn import to ClearCase: see "[Moving from SVN to ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031389/moving-from-svn-to-clearcase)"