# how to copy all the branches and source from svn to clear case

Tags: svn, unix, clearcase

My project has decide to move from SVN to clearcase. So we need to move all the source code, branches everything from SVN to clear case.

Can any one provide details on how can we move files from SVN to clear case.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031389/moving-from-svn-to-clearcase

Comment: In above link this link is mentioned. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258843

Comment: I agree with my own answer from 3 years ago ;)

Comment: i am so sorry you have to take a monumental step backwards.