# we are migrating to clearcase from SVN. Is it possible to retain version history?

Tags: svn, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are migrating from SVN to clearcase UCM due to our organizational policy.

We were told that version history will not be retained.

But we are afraid that we will lose valuable information.

Is there any way to migrate to clearcase with version history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving from SVN to ClearCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031389/moving-from-svn-to-clearcase)

Comment: @AaronDigulla - answer (accepted) in linked question is obsiously outdated and just wrong

Comment: @LazyBadger: That's not a reason to open the question again. Improve the original one instead.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla that question is not at all talking about retaining version history. I knew how to migrate but i want to know is there a possibility to retain history

Comment: You're moving from SVN to ClearCase? I originally answered the question the other way around because I couldn't believe ANYONE would be going from SVN to CC. Your organization is making a big, big mistake. Why are they doing this?

Comment: you should look for a new job.

Answer (score 0):

> I knew how to migrate but I want to know is there a possibility to retain history

Generally, the history isn't preserved or partially kept.
Plus not every SVN metadata are easily imported/kept in ClearCase.

That is why I usually do partial history import (with `clearfsimport` as I mentioned in [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032705/6309)), or through more modern scripts: import of certain main revisions from SVN to ClearCase, with baselines set for each import (instead if importing *all* SVN revision)/

Answer (score -2):

[Subversion Connector to IBM Rational ClearCase](http://www.collab.net/products/integrations/svn2cc) (svn2cc) from CollabNet is single and best possible answer on your question