# How to use clearfsimport to import files into an empty VOB

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I created a VOB and a snapshot view that loads it. The VOB is empty and I wanted to add some files to initialize it, but I got errors for all files that I wanted to import. Here is the details.

The VOB is created by this command:

```
ct mkvob -tag /vobs/sqlite -comment "testing VOB for Sqlite" -public /var/clearcase/vobs/sqlite.vbs
```

The view is created by this command:

```
ct mkview -tag sqlite-dev -snapshot /home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev
```

The config spec is:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST 
load /vobs/sqlite
```

I checked out the "vobs/sqlite".

In the view directory `/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev`, I run `clearfsimport` to import some files:

```
clearfsimport -rec /home/clearcase/tmp/sqlite-3.6.23.1/* vobs/sqlite
```

But I got errors for all files and directories. Fore example, for the file "VERSIONS", I saw errors like:

```
Creating element "vobs/sqlite/VERSION".
clearfsimport: Error: Unable to lookup "VERSION" in "/vobs/sqlite@@/main/CHECKEDOUT": no version selected in configuration specification.
clearfsimport: Error: Unable to access "/vobs/sqlite/VERSION": no version selected in configuration specification.
clearfsimport: Warning: Trouble updating name "VERSION" in snapshot view: error detected by ClearCase subsystem.
A separate update may need to be performed in order to reflect the results of the operation in the snapshot view.
clearfsimport: Warning: Unable to check if new version of "vobs/sqlite/VERSION" is identical.
clearfsimport: Warning: Element "vobs/sqlite/VERSION" is no longer being loaded and will not be updated as part of this operation.
    version "/main/1".
```

Can anybody please point out what I did wrong here? Should I change the config spec somehow?

---

Updates after I tried VonC's answer.

Thanks for the response. I tried to run `clearfsimport` again and I saw some different errors:

```
Validating directory "/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite/tool".
clearfsimport: Error: Cannot checkout a directory when directory doesn't exist in the snapshot view.
clearfsimport: Error: Could not checkout directory "/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite/tool".
Validating element "/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite/VERSION".
clearfsimport: Error: Could not access "/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite/VERSION".
clearfsimport: Warning: Trouble importing element "/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite/VERSION".
```

`tool` is a directory and `VERSION` is a file. The same error happens to all files/directories.

The CC is installed on Linux, so I cannot try the ClearCase explorer.

I tried the full path but I saw the same errors.

I am running these command as root, I guess "-nset" won't help. I tried adding it but still saw the same error.

Are there other ways to add files if I only want to add them once?

Comment: The config spec is good, but I suspect a path error in the `clearfsimport` command. See my answer.

Comment: Try without the '*' just to see how it goes.

Comment: Still no luck when tried without "*". Is it possible my VOB has problems?

Comment: @X. Ma: You vob should be fine, but try with a dynamic view to see if it works better (`/view/MyView/vobs/sqlite`)

Comment: @X. Ma: also do you have access to the chat? (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57017/feedback-wanted-three-day-test-run-of-the-chat). If yes, join me in the sandbox room and leave a message to @VonC: I will create a 'clearcase' room then (Note: you must have 20 rep on meta.stackoverflow.com though...)

Comment: @X. Ma: also make sure you don't have anything checked-out before making the `clearfsimport`.

Comment: @X. Ma: any news on that `clearfsimport`? Did you check for any checked out file? Did you use a dynamic view?

Answer (score 1):

- Try the `clearfsimport` without checkouting the vob first.
- Try adding a file to the vob through the ClearCase explorer (just to see if it works)
- **Try specifying the full path of the vob** when clearfsimporting: `/home/clearcase/working/sqlite-dev/vobs/sqlite`

Note: you can also use a dynamic view for this kind of operation (that avoid any "update view" error regarding the workspace, since a dynamic view has no need to update its -- network managed -- workspace)

See also ["How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively) for more on the `clearfsimport` options: the '`-nset`' option might also be needed here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried what you suggested but still no luck. I updated my original question with what I did.