# what data to collect for migrate code from mainframe to clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am just curious what data or info.
I have to collect to migrate the code from mainframe to ClearCase.

Any tutorial will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about data without history (just a bunch of files), then all you need is to:

- be able to export that group of files
- import it in a ClearCase view (typically using **`clearfsimport`**)

See:

- "[How to use `clearfsimport` to import files into an empty VOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251292/how-to-use-clearfsimport-to-import-files-into-an-empty-vob/3252331#3252331)" and
- "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively)"