# Can the ClearCase Eclipse plug-in circumvent the need to run CC on a compatible Linux kernel?

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to circumvent the restrictions imposed by IBM on the use of CC (version 7.0.1.0) in an environment where I have next to no ability to change the CC version.
I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is "No." but I'm hoping there might be a "No but..." that might lead to a solution to my problem:

- I must develop with CC on Windows (using either a dynamic or snapshot view)
- but I desperately want to develop on a Ubuntu 11.10 (or more recent) system.

My thinking is that the Eclipse plug-in for CC is a pure Java client and does not have native file system constraints, especially for a snapshot view.
Admittedly, this could easily be wishful thinking.
If so, is there some other approach that would take the Linux kernel version out of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual setup I have seen in this case is to develop on Ubuntu in a Linux filesystem shared and accessible from Windows (through a samba share, for instance).

That way:

- you develop in your favorite OS
- you still have a snapshot view on Windows that you can update through [a `clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309) (which will import whatever directory structure you want)

What you cannot do is mix two different views (one Windows, one Linux) on the same path (one through the samba, one in the Linux disk).

However, if you have only *one* ClearCase (ie, one on Windows), you could, in theory, create a snapshot view *directly* on the Samba shared path (provided your view storage is stored on your view server).
That would avoid the task of keeping synchronized two different trees (one, shared through Samba, one local to your Windows workstation) through `clearfsimport`.

---

The [OP pajato0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91443/pajato0) confirms:

> This is almost what I do now: the Windows share is CIFS mounted on the Linux system but Eclipse (with the CC plugin) must run on Windows.
>   **I was striving to have Eclipse run on Linux WITH the ability to check-in, check-out**, etc without having to switch over to Windows

2 comments:

- if you want to checkout/checkin anything from Linux (through an Eclipse plugin or even manually through cleartool command-line interface), you will need a local installation of ClearCase on your Linux. (so not good in your case)
- OR: if you can install a **[CCRC server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629)** (not necessarily on the ClearCase server itself, but at least on any Windows server you want), then you will [have access to the CCRC Eclipse plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412271) with the update site http://yourserver:12080/ccrc/update.
  That means you will be able to checkout/checkin from your Linux server *without any local ClearCase installation*.

Comment: This is almost what I do now: the Windows share is CIFS mounted on the Linux system but Eclipse (with the CC plugin) must run on Windows.  I was striving to have Eclipse run on Linux WITH the ability to check-in, check-out, etc without having to switch over to Windows.

Comment: @pajato0: I understand, but if you want to checkout/checkin anything from Linux (through an Eclipse plugin or even manually through `cleartool` command-line interface), you will need a local installation of ClearCase on your Linux.

Comment: Clearly, I do not like the answer, but I accept that it is true and accurate. :-)

Comment: @pajato0 I have edited my answer and added a new option you could consider: no local ClearCase installation on your Linux server, and yet checkout/checkins from your Linux Eclipse!