# Rollback via label in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I take care of a couple of extremly large projects. These projects are also divided into smaller del-projects some are delivered as a large project at one time. The problem I am having is that when all these small projects are merged into our release branch its dam near impossible for me to rollback 1000's of files. 
I am currently rethinking our branching strategy. Everything now is being merged with a label. We are also merging everything to a build-test branch before we even think about dumping it into our release branch.

If I need to do a rollback based on label what is the best way to do this? I have a few scripts but can't get this to work.. hopefully some ClearCase god here can help ASAP!

Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rollback to a label, you can:

- create a dynamic view
- edit its config spec to select said label
- use that dynamic view as source for a **[`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively)** into your main view (the one with the latest releases)

A `clearfsimport -rmname` ("mirror") will update/add/remove the files in the destination view with the files from the source (which is, here, your dynamic view set to the label you want to rollback).