# ClearCase Views From One Computer Copied to New Computer?

Tags: clearcase

Yesterday I received a new computer at work.  My old computer had several Clearcase views (snapshots) containing a number of files that were stilled checked out.  The process for building my new machine copied the directory containing my Clearcase view to my new machine.

My new machine's ClearCase now has no idea that those directories are ClearCase views and therefore that they contain checked out files that I'd like to keep.

How can I associate those directories to ClearCase so I get back to the state that they were in on my old machine (i.e. the directories are controlled by ClearCase and checked out files are recognized as such)?

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to:

- unregister and rmtag your previous view,
  (because registering the same view on a new computer doesn't work well)
  See "[How to delete clearcase views created by other users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782424/how-to-delete-clearcase-views-created-by-other-users/9782443#9782443)"
- `mkview` a new view on your new computer,
  See "[Proper 'cleartool mkview' for ClearCase Snapshot view creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation/1207516#1207516)"
- and `clearfsimport -rmname` your current modifications in that new view on your new computer.
  (as in "[Rollback via label in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641817/6309)")

Comment: Thanks Von.  Could you clarify the 3rd bullet?  At this point I'd have the old view (we'll call it oldview), and my new view (we'll call it newview) directories.  <br />  Do I run clearfsimport while in the oldview directory?  And that'll stick the source objs into newview?

Comment: @Todd the `clearfsimport` is run in the target destination (your new view), importing any directory of your choice (in your case, your old View). What that will do is to update (checkout / checkin) the files that you have modified. Not that said files will be checked-in though.

Comment: Thanks Von.  I'm back in action!