# what is the best way to converge code from different folder in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I need some suggestions on the following issue.

Currently, I have code in this stream:tll_ltr_nyc@/ttl_pvob mastered at NYC (P_NYC folder of ttl_vob) and I would like to merge those code with latest changes in stream:aaa_ltr_lax@/ttl_pvob mastered at LAX (P_LAX folder of ttl_pvob). what will be the best way to proceed with converging code from one stream to another within same project vob but within two different folders?

Any help will be appreciated !!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest practical solution, especially if we are talking about a one-time merge, would be to:

- [`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309) the code you want in the right folder, in a sub-stream of your local stream
- then deliver deliver that sub-stream to your stream, achieving the merge that way.

You can actually repeat that process, updating your sub-stream with a new `clearfsimport`, and delivering again.

That way, you side-step completely the multisite mastership issue, and are still able to integrate code from a different site, with a different directory back into your local stream.