# SVN project import to ClearCase

Tags: svn, clearcase

I have a client who is rather insistent about using Clearcase. Are there any tools/scripts that would allow my team to import SVN projects?  My team projects actually will be in SVN…. How do I import SVN project to Clearcase?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258843) does mention:

> ClearCase does not provide a tool to import from Subversion to maintain version history.
>
> If you are not interested in maintaining version history and merely wish to start from the latest version or a preselected configuration, you can use the clearfsimport command. Review the ClearCase Command Reference Guide on the topic of [`clearfsimport` (`cleartool man clearfsimport`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309) for more information.
>
> If you require version history, you may want to evaluate the open source tool [svn2cc](http://sarovar.org/projects/svn2cc).

That project might be obsolete, but is detailed in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014105083):

> The utility does it in one two ways
>
> - The fist is to create a series of batch files that need to be executed after the utility runs. The batch files, when executed, will then insert the source files into CC.
> - The second is to directly insert the records into CC from the utility. You can choose what option is best for you project.
>
> The SVN dump file contains all the data you need. That includes the source file and its associated meta-data (history, author, etc). Your SVN administrator will be able to generate the dump files for you.

---

This [GitHub script](https://gist.github.com/inancsevinc/2367505) illustrates the "simple" approach (clearfsimport), allowing you to import successive svn revision that you mention one by one:

```
@echo off

SET CC_VOB_DIR=
SET CC_VIEW_TAG=
SET CC_COMPONENT_NAME=
SET CC_VOB_NAME=
SET TMP_SVN_EXPORT_DIR=
SET SVN_URL=

@echo deleting directory %TMP_SVN_EXPORT_DIR%

rd /S /Q %TMP_SVN_EXPORT_DIR%
svn export %SVN_URL% %TMP_SVN_EXPORT_DIR% --force
clearfsimport -nsetevent -recurse -rmname %TMP_SVN_EXPORT_DIR% %CC_VOB_DIR%

IF %1==-b (
cleartool mkbl -view %CC_VIEW_TAG% -full -component %CC_COMPONENT_NAME%@\%CC_VOB_NAME% %CC_COMPONENT_NAME%
)
```

This is similar to [this thread answer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014834469):

> The way I do it is to come up with a list of svn tags that represent milestone builds or releases and then import those oldest to newest, building up a version history and sometimes even several branches in the process.
>   Depending on how "structured" your cvs or svn or .... repository is, importing everything often results in very bad version trees. I had only one case where they were very particular about the cvs branching where the export/import worked without fuss and the result was something you could and would want to work with in CC.
>
> So spend some time analyzing your svn repository and how it would translate into CC branches and identify the tags and create CC config specs and clearfsimport oldest to newest.