# Subversion to Clearcase migration

Tags: svn, clearcase

What steps or tools do I need to use in order to migrate a SVN repo to a ClearCase Vob?

What needs to be taken into account for such a migration?

Answer (score 0):

One starting point would be the official IBM page: [**Migrating data from Subversion to ClearCase**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258843): there is no official tool, so you can use [`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070750/6309) instead to import one revision into a ClearCase vob.

You can find a script importing revisions after revisions in "[SVN project import to ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16672214/6309)".
However, that supposes you import into the right ClearCase view, with the right config spec in order to put a given revision in the right branch.

> spend some time analyzing your svn repository and how it would translate into CC branches and identify the tags and create CC config specs and clearfsimport oldest to newest.