# How to add an existing VOB element source file to another existing same VOB directory tree?

Tags: clearcase

I have a directory name ABCD containing a set of files under Clearcase VOB within a directory TEST1 . I want to retain that structure of the existing directory **tree** as is.

```
 - TEST1

    * ABCD
```

But I also have another directory under same VOB with the name EFGH within a directcory **tree** TEST2.

```
 - TEST2

    * EFGH
```

I want to add the directory ABCD and it its contents under EFGH without disturbing TEST1 directory tree at all.
       Essentially I want to *reuse* ABCD directory tree under two directory **TREE** within same VOB,

```
- TEST2

    * EFGH  
       * ABCD
```

I don't want to use **cleartool ln** command.

What is the way out?
Thank you.
Regards
Pashan

Answer (score 0):

No [`cleartool ln`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm) means you would have to duplicate `ABCD` in `EFGH`.

You can easily do that with a [`clearfsimport`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm) command (see "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)")

```
 cd TEST2/EFGH
 clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /path/to/ABCD .
```

(Remove the `-preview` when the output looks like the import you want to do).