# how to run mkelem command in command prompt

Tags: cmd, cleartool

i execuated the **mkelem *** command through cleartool command prompt
but when i run the same command through command promp (cleartool mkelem *) it shows error 
what can i do

the error is

***V:\Pold_Build\CCAD_REPO\CC_Training\vivekananda\guntur>cleartool mkelem -nc ****
Created element "*" (type "compressed_file").
cleartool: Error: Checked out version, but could not copy data to "*" in view: I
nvalid argument.
Correct the condition, then uncheckout and re-checkout the element.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "*".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mkelem for multiple elements: use clearfsimport, as mentioned in "[Creating a new subdirectory structure in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321)".

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\sourceDir\ChildDirectory5 m:\MyView\MyVob\ParentDirectory
```

If those files are already in a view, use as a destination *another* (dynamic) view (with the same config spec)

Any file from the first view that was *already* versioned will be left unmodified in the destination view.

But any file that was new (and untracked or private) in the first view will be added to source control in the destination view.