# Why clearfsimport command adds file to source control with a size zero?

Tags: cmd, clearcase

I use **`clearfsimport`** command  the file is added to source control but:

- the file size becomes zero and
- keep files are created.

In the version tree of ClearCase, the version number of that file is zero.

How can I fix this in order for the `clearfsimport` to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, when using clearfsimport (as in "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)")

- that your source is different from your destination

  ```
  clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\sourceDir\* m:\MyView\MyVob\MyDestinationDirectory
  ```

(Here I use the -preview to check first what the import would do)

- that your destination config spec allows you to create new files (in the current branch or in the new one)

  ```
  element * CHECKEDOUT
  element * /main/LATEST

  or

  element * CHECKEDOUT

  element * .../newBranch/LATEST
  element * /main/0 -mkbranch newBranch
  element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch newBranch
  ```