# Provide version to independent files in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

I recently started usage of clear case tools for maintenance of code in better way. But after some days my "Company" forgot to take licence from IBM as result I cannot **CHECK-IN** my code into clearcase. To continue my coding i created a separate folder in other drive and copied code solution in that folder. I and my colleague modified around "9865" files of solution within "45" working days. Now a "Company" borrowed a licence for me and I able to access code clear case tool successfully.

Problem is:

> How to check in my "9865" files into clearcase in better way?

I tried:

> Copied all solution into Snapshot view folder location. but, all
>   changed files are showing **"hijack"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use **[`clearfsimport`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm?lang=en)**: that will automatically checkout, and import your 9865 in one command.

Make sure to update your snapshot view first, in order to restore its original content.
Then `clearfsimport` those files.

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /path/to/sourceDir\* </myview/VOB>
```

The `clearfsimport` command will detect the files added or modified, and do the checkouts for you.
If you are using an UCM view, set an activity first.

The source from where `clearfsimport` does that copy can be any regular folder.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. This will import files in development branch or in main branch? Additionally what about newly added files?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade it will import the files in the branch currently managed by the view: choose a view already set to checkout files in the *right* branch, and `clearfsimport` simply will use that. `clearfsimport` is just there to checkout and import: it doesn't know in which branch, that is entirely controled by the destination view config spec.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade yes, but check your config spec: if it says `-mkbranch xxx` (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014592/6309), it would create a branch `xxx` starting from the eye (unless the eye points already to the `xxx` branch)

Comment: No issues if it create branch. What about newly added files? Is this command add files to source control?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade again, it depends on your config spec (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014592/6309): a `/main/0` rule is needed as a new file will first create a `/main/0` placeholder version, and then create a version `1` in the current branch defined by the config spec. But yes, `clearfsimport` will those new files to source control for you.

Comment: This one is my config spec "element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../Working/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch Working
element * /main/LATEST
load \OSD_Suprime\Suprime" will it do?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade ok. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29014592/6309: you are missing a `element * /main/0 -mkbranch Working`, if you want you new imported elements to be added directly in the `Working` branch.

Comment: Yup, I looked into it. latest version of my main branch is main/24. so i thought main/LATEST or main/24 should be there. please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade `/main/LATEST` is fine and will allow for new files to be created in `/main`. But existing files would be created in `Working` branch (even when the latest version is in `/main`), according to your config spec. So make sure that is indeed what you want to do.

Comment: Okay, thanks for discussion. Will try and let you know. Thank you so much but.

Comment: I tried "F:\abc>clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset *  santosh_view59\TEMP_TEST\dot_net_1" but giving me error.  clearfsimport: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "santosh_view59\TEMP_TEST\dot_net_1".

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade you need to provide the path of the view/vob in which you import. `santosh_view59\TEMP_TEST\dot_net_1` doesn't seem to be a valid Windows path.

Comment: I tried F:\abc\windowsformsapplication1>clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset "F:\abc\windowsformsapplication1\windowsformsapplication1\form1.cs"  "E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view60\AOP_TEST\dot_net_1\windowsformsapplication1"
E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view60\AOP_TEST\dot_net_1\windowsformsapplication1\form1.cs  new element
E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view60\AOP_TEST\dot_net_1\windowsformsapplication1  new directory version. but nothing happened on server.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade see other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24773174/6309

Comment: When i remove -nset option i am getting "clearfsimport: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or privileged user." But i able to check in check out with "clearcase Explorer".

Comment: Yes, you need the nset option

Comment: once i removed -preview all thinks working properly.

Comment: Great. Preview is indeed for previewing first, before actually importing.

Comment: I am getting "clearfsimport: Error: Type manager "text_file_delta" failed create_version operation." for some files.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawadea that would be a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514335/text-file-delta-failed-create-version-operation-in-clearcase