# text_file_delta failed create_version operation in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

Continuing my previous post: [Provide version to independent files in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467305/provide-version-to-independent-files-in-clearcase). Now I able to execute clear case import command but with some errors. Following are some errors occurred while import:

```
clearfsimport: Error: Could not checkin "E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view57\Temp_TEST\AspNET\Scripts\WebForms\MSAjax\MicrosoftAjax.js".
clearfsimport: Warning: Trouble importing element "E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view57\Temp_TEST\AspNET\Scripts\WebForms\MSAjax\MicrosoftAjax.js".
Creating element "E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view57\Temp_TEST\AspNET\Scripts\WebForms\MSAjax\MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js".
Created branch "TEST_TEMP" from "E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view57\Temp_TEST\AspNET\Scripts\WebForms\MSAjax\MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js" version "\main\0".
clearfsimport: Error: Type manager "text_file_delta" failed create_version operation.
```

Following is my import command:

> clearfsimport -rec -nset -comment "Commit test"  F:\abc\ASPNET* E:\CC_Work\FromCC\santosh_view57\Temp_TEST\ASPNET

And config spec is following:

> element * CHECKEDOUT
>
> element * .../TEST_TEMP/LATEST
>
> element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch TEST_TEMP
>
> element * /main/LATEST
>
> load \Temp_TEST

Same file is able to check out and check in using "**ClearCase Expoler**" GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to change the type manager associated to js files, as their content could not always be compatible with what a text_file_delta manager expects.

See "[Type manager `text_file_delta` failed create_version operation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21222072)" for concrete examples.

[This technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21259086) lists the limitations which makes a text file fail:

- Type manager size limitation - File too large
- Text files that contain binary data - Contains a '\000'
- Line exceeding 8000 bytes
- Corrupt source container - not the highest on its branch

I have seen issue with the first 3.

If you have to change its type, see [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21146932).

Comment: Why it is working with GUI? And i am very new in clear case all those links are bouncers only. :(

Comment: Is there is way to skip all these conditions to check in.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade skip, not that I know. A simple `cleartool chtype compressed_file` done on each problematic file should allow for the `clearfsimport` to complete successfully.

Comment: Thank you, There are lots of problematic files.

Comment: I applied same command for all files. But while check out one file always hijacked.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade could you try that same operation in a dynamic view?

Comment: Actully this is happening due to "case sensative" name. In cc file name is "anc.cpp" while in my local code name is "ANC.cpp". How to avoid this?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade do you have both files versioned?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade then you simply cannot do even a checkout (or a clearfsimport) on Windows. You need first to rename one (in a Unix view) before being to work with those files on Windows.