# What is the most efficient way of adding new files to ClearCase dynamic view by using a text file containing list of changed files?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have a certain folder(named SDK) containing many other folders as a VOB element in my dynamic view.

```
/vobs/tools/SDK
```

I also have a updated version of that folder elsewhere as view private (as flat files).

```
/homes/user/SDK
```

I need to add files which were introduced in the updated version to the checked in version which did not have them. I have a text file containing all the files which were newly introduced in the updated version.

```
/homes/user/files.txt
```

Contents of files.txt

```
./a/b/abc.cpp
./s/t/xyz.cpp
.
.
.
```

Which is the best way to have these files checked in at at appropriate location?

`clearfsimport` will not work because it takes the leaf of the source path and checks that at the target VOB location.

i.e.

```
clearfsimport -nset /homes/user/SDK/a/b/abc.cpp /vobs/tools/SDK
clearfsimport -nset /homes/user/SDK/s/t/xyz.cpp /vobs/tools/SDK
```

wouldn't create the `/a/b/` and `/s/t/` directories in `/vobs/tools/`.

I could use `mkelem` but that would require me to manually create the directory `/a/` then `/a/b/` and then copy the file `abc.cpp` and checkin back the newly created directories and the file itself.

Can someone suggest the  most efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet [**`clearfsimport`**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm?lang=en) should work (to [import multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)):

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /homes/user/SDK /vobs/tools/SDK
# or
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /homes/user/SDK/\* /vobs/tools/SDK
```

That should import all elements, but checkout and update only the ones modified, and create the one missing.

All that in `/vobs/tools/SDK`, not `/vobs/tools`.

---

Since there are too many files in `/vobs/tools/SDK`, copy the ones which have been modified in `/vobs/tools/SDK_to_import`, with their exact folder structure (like `/homes/user/SDK_to_import/a/b/abc.cpp`).

The `clearfsimport`, by default, will not remove the files of the destination folder which are not present in the source folder.
But it will update those files in the destination folder `/vobs/tools/SDK`.

Comment: But i dont want it to check for other files because there are around 3500 files in the SDK folder. I just want the `clearfsimport` be to be restricted to the files i have given it through the text files there reducing the time

Comment: @Onkar let clearfsimport do the work: it is all automated for you.

Comment: @Onkar actually, even simpler: copy those files in a structure `/homes/user/SDK_to_import` where they would be the only files. And `clearfsimport` that. By default, `clearfsimport` will not remove the files of the destination folder which are not present in the source folder.

Comment: U mean to say the dir structure should look like 

`/homes/user/SDK_to_import/a/b/abc.cpp`

???

Comment: @Onkar yes, same dir structure, but with only the files you want to `clearfsimport`.

Comment: @Onkar Great! I have edited the answer to reflect the actual solution.