# Unable to see Checkout Option in Clearcase explorer for a development view

Tags: clearcase

After Creating a View in ClearCase Project Explorer, I was trying to add my projects into the developement view through clearcase explorer, but I am not finding the option "add to source control" while right clicking the projects that I've added. Please help out here

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your sources of your project are in the created view:

- either in `c:/path/to/my/view/vobtag` (snpashot view)
- or in `m:/myView/vobtag` (dynamic view)

If they are not, you would need to do a **[`clearfsimport`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm?lang=en)** of the folder where your sources are to the view.

See "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)"

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\path\to\sourceDir\* c:\Tests\aVobTag
```

---

> now when I want to check out those projects by right clicking, I am getting only "search" option, I want to see the other options ex:Checkout

Those sources are not yet added to source control.
Checkout would be available only if the sources are first added to source control.

Instead of pasting the sources directly in the view, it is best to do a `clearfsimport` of the sources (stored elsewhere) into the view, as described above.

Comment: You can try it with `clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /path/to/sourceDir\* </myview/VOB>`

Comment: Yes I have projects in the view that I've created, but I am unable to see the other options in clearcase explorer while right clicking except search

Comment: @TulasiRaju can you edit your question and add a screenshot? (or just the link to a screenshot, and I will edit your question again to actually include the picture, if you don't have enough rep yet). Can you also add what a `cleartool ls` returns when you are in your view, where your sources are?

Comment: I would like to elaborate my question, I just created a development stream in the project explorer, then I created a view under this stream. I gave a path for this view in c:\Test directory and navigated to this directory and pasted the projects.Now opened the cleacase explorer under views section I can able to see my view in the dropdown, I clicked on the view of the developemnt stream now I can able to see the projects that I have added, but now when I want to check out those projects by right clicking, I am getting only "search" option, I want to see the other options ex:Checkout

Comment: @TulasiRaju I have edited my answer to answer your comment. But do edit your question to add more information there. Follow the Stack Overflow tour to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/tour