# How to avoid extra files when using clearfsimport?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

My fonts were delivered to the branch with the command

```
clearfsimport -rec -nset <Source> <target>
```

My problem is: supose in my next deliver I delete 10 files in different folders, I saw that there are many fonts in my first version and now I have fonts from my version1 that were deleted.
I need to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm), you should consider the `-rmname` option:

> For all source-name arguments that are directories, performs an `rmname` operation on elements that are already in the VOB but are not present in the source directory.
>   If used in combination with `-recurse`, performs this `rmname` operation in all directories traversed.

That way, your next import will remove the 10 files you have deleted in your folders (that you are importing)

(I usually combine that option [with the options `-preview` and `-nset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309))

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the "all source-name arguments that are DIRECTORIES" part. Doesn't that mean it will _not_ remove files, only directories?

EDIT: I will try this out at work tomorrow. I don't have a ClearCase machine here with me right now.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see that now. I misunderstood what the reference said. The " ...that are directories" part was in reference to the path name arguments that can be passed to clearfsimport, since one can just as well specify a file instead of a directory tree, and in such a case the -rmname behavior would obviously make no sense. :-)