# Equivalent of mkdir -p for cleartool mkdir

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

UNIX `mkdir` has the `-p` flag that creates the parent directories if they don't exist. Is there an equivalent in cleartool for that? Obviously `cleartool mkdir foo/bar/` doens't work when `foo` doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a file in the directory structure and use mkelem -mkpath...

I created a "temp1" directory, and a "temp2" directory, and a "temp.txt" file in one of my sandbox vobs, then added the file to source control with -mkpath from the parent of the "temp1" view private directory.

```
PS M:\tempview\foobarf\Documents> cleartool mkelem -mkpath .\temp1\temp2\temp.txt
Creating parent directory element ".\temp1\temp2".
Creating parent directory element ".\temp1".
Created directory element ".\temp1".
Checking out parent directory ".\temp1".
Created directory element ".\temp1\temp2".
Checking out parent directory ".\temp1\temp2".
Creation comments for ".\temp1\temp2\temp.txt":
Test1.
.
Created element ".\temp1\temp2\temp.txt" (type "utf16le_file").
Checked out ".\temp1\temp2\temp.txt" from version "\main\0".
```

It's UTF-16LE because Powershell's Locale is wide character and the "temp.txt" was created using "dir > temp1\temp2\temp.txt".

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need, I just need some time to test.

Comment: No sorry, it doesn't work for creating a directory _only_. `Unable to determine view for "foo/bar/": No such file or directory.`

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis Any particular reason for needing an empty directory structure as VOB objects? Winkins don't need the directories to exist, you'll see messages like "created directory .. for derived object winkin".

Comment: Sure! I _already_ have some files _elsewhere_ and I want to move them there.

Comment: Why not simply create and then remove a bogus file with this command line?
`dir > foo\bar\oof\deleteme & cleartool mkelem -mkpath -ci -nc foo\bar\oof\deleteme &cleartool rmelem foo\bar\oof\deleteme`

Comment: Because I could more "simply" create a script that will get a `/very/annoyingly/big/directory/` and stack the `ct mkdir` calls in there. I am looking for a missing `-p` of `ct mkdir`. If it doesn't exist then it doesn't. It's clearcase after all, I can't expect much...

Comment: Please create a Request for Enhancement (RFE) in the RFE community at [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/) It really boils down to "noone has asked for this..." And IBM/HCL likes RFE's because they mean people are using the toolset.

Answer (score 0):

`cleartool mkelem -mkpath` is a good option when adding *one* file.

But if you have *multiple* files to add, in a tree structure which does not exist yet, don't forget about [`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm): it can [import flat files to a branch](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228449) in one command, and will create any missing folder for you.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36478572/6309): `clearfsimport -rec -nset <Source> <target>`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, _but_ I already found your suggestion of `clearfsimport` in another answer and I don't find it useful. I just need to avoid stacking the `mkdir`s not interested in the tree. :)