# Permission denied clearfsimport

Tags: clearcase

When I execute clearfsimport -preview -recurse -rmname source* target\

clearfsimport: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or privileged user.

Where have I to check the permission?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run clearfsimport without the "-nsetevent" option, you have to be the VOB owner of the target VOB or the privileged user, as the message tells you, so apparently this is not the case.

Determine the VOB owner by running "cleartool describe vob:" for the target VOB. Then check your own credentials for example with the "creds" tool that comes with ClearCase. That will give you the information to determine the cause of the permission problem.

Comment: Be warned, if you use -nsetevent, all the files you import will have their time set to the current time. Once that happens, clearfsimport will not import "older" files on top of these "new ones"