# How to extablish Sync between VisualSVN and ClearCase

Tags: svn, clearcase, visualsvn-server

Can any one explain on how we can do the sync between VisualSVN and ClearCase:

VisualSVN and ClearCase are installed on Windows machines,

One way sync is enough as of now (from SVN to ClearCase).

I am able to write a perl script if needed.
So if any one guide the steps then I can able to write the Hook steps.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne one-way sync is enough, you can setup a hook which will do a [`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm). See "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)"

The idea is to:

- [export an SVN working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html) (to get clean copy of your working tree without the `.svn` directory, since it is [not easy to exclude a folder when using `clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013729521)).
  You can use the [`svn export` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html).
- import this clean working tree into a ClearCase view with clearfsimport.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a product of Collabnet's called "svn2cc" and is at:

https://www.open.collab.net/products/integrations/svn2cc/getit.html

It's GPL, and also available through:
https://clearsvn.open.collab.net/