# How do I associate a ClearQuest TASK with a cleartool mkelem command?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearquest

I am attempting to check in hundreds of new files in *Base* ClearCase.  Due to network and server issues, I am wanting to write a batch script of cleartool commands to add each file to source control.  All files will be checked in under a single ClearQuest task.

I have tried selecting all the files and adding all at once via the context menu, but after selecting the ClearQuest task association and choosing "apply to all", I am still having a dialog box pop up for every file, asking me to confirm the association.

I want to write a list of commands like:

```
cleartool mkelem -c "SCR ... / TASK ... - blah blah" filename.ext
```

However, I don't know how to associate the change with the TASK, and I don't see any documentation for doing this in Base CC/CQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't write a script adding new files throug mkelem: if you can isolate those files in their own folder (or tree of folders) *outside* a view, then you can import them *into* a view (snapshot or dynamic) through **[`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm)**.

`clearfsimport` is made for that, and will checkout the parent folder of the files to add, and do the required `mkelem` for each file for you.

See also "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)":

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset c:\sourceDir\* m:\MyView\MyVob\MyDestinationDirectory
```

You will need first to use `cleartool settask` in order to set the ClearQuest task for the destination view used for this import.
See "[How to configure base ClearCase to use the Change Management integration with ClearQuest](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633122)".

As the [OP Darthfett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936083/darthfett) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498786/how-do-i-associate-a-clearquest-task-with-a-cleartool-mkelem-command/39499050?noredirect=1#comment66315741_39499050):

> However, as I am using ClearCase 7.*, there is no `settask` command.
>   As a workaround, it looks like using `set CQCC_AUTO_ASSOCIATE=<TASK ID>` will work ([see here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcccq_autoassoc_usng.htm))

Comment: This looks like the right answer -- using cleartool settask.  However, as I am using ClearCase 7.*, there is no settask command.  As a workaround, it looks like using `set CQCC_AUTO_ASSOCIATE=<TASK ID>` will work (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcccq_autoassoc_usng.htm)).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Darthfett No problem, and well spotted for the settask workaround. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.